# Utility to import/export data in SQLServer

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

We have built an desktop(windows) application that needs SQL Server to store the data. Now if we do any changes on database side, we need to backup the database of user's application, amend our changes and restore it back to user's application.

We have written code to backup & restore the .bak file in the application that works fine.

But now we need to build an online utility where user could upload the data file, then our changes could ammend and then they could download the update data to restore.

Please suggest me some ideas to implement this feature.

P.S.: I have posted the question in the zone where i felt it was correct. Please change to appropriate zone (if required)

thanks!

Comment: by "changes", do you mean schema changes or changes in data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write migrations with [Migrator.NET](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) to update your schema and deploy schema changes as a runnable update to your clients.

Here is an example from the [Getting Started documentation](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/wiki/GettingStarted):

```
using Migrator.Framework;
using System.Data;

namespace DBMigration
{
        [Migration(20080401110402)]
        public class CreateUserTable_001 : Migration
        {
                public void Up()
                {
                        Database.CreateTable("User",
                                new Column("UserId", DbType.Int32, ColumnProperties.PrimaryKeyWithIdentity),
                                new Column("Username", DbType.AnsiString, 25)
                                );
                }

                public void Down()
                {
                        Database.RemoveTable("User");
                }
        }
}
```

There are nice wrappers for adding/removing columns, but you can execute any arbitrary SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Why not provide your user the script that they can run (or you provide it as a part of setup or have a simple utility to run the script) on the database to apply the changes.

Typically, as you make database side changes at your dev environment, generate scripts for the same and maintain them till you release the new version of your application.

Comment: That is not something acceptable to client as that would mean to fire the scripts to 100 something client's users.

Comment: @Xor power, this implies that each user has a copy of application and database. How does user get the new version of app? If it's a setup then u can have a custom action in ur setup that would run the script upgrading the db. If you provide new version as a zip (or set of files) then upgrade logic should be built into the app code. e.g. app when started can check what is a db version (you have to maintain version info in some table) and may run the embedded script to upgrade database. Believe me that automated solutions are much better from both user experience and support perspective.